# Error: No Retrofit annotation found. (parameter #2)

Tags: android, retrofit

I have this Interface:

```
public interface InterfazAguaHttp {

@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/")
Call<String> saveContador(@Field("contador") Long contador, Callback<String> callBack);
}
```

The rest of the code is this:

```
Retrofit builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
                            .baseUrl(ValoresGlobales.urlServlet)
                            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                            .build();
                    InterfazAguaHttp interfaz = builder.create(InterfazAguaHttp.class);
                        Call<String> respuesta = interfaz.saveContador(93847597L, new Callback<String>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(Response<String> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
                                //Some logging
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                                //Some logging
                            }
                        });
```

This is all inside a try-catch block. In the catch, I am receiving this error:

```
Error: No Retrofit annotation found. (parameter #2) for method InterfazAguaHttp.saveContador
```

How could I get rid of this error, and still have my callback?

Thank you.

Comment: change your method to `void` or use `enqueue`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

change your interface method to this

```
public interface InterfazAguaHttp {

@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/")
Call<String> saveContador(@Field("contador") Long contador);
}
```

and the rest of the code like this

```
Retrofit builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
                            .baseUrl(ValoresGlobales.urlServlet)
                            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                            .build();
                    InterfazAguaHttp interfaz = builder.create(InterfazAguaHttp.class);
                        Call<String> respuesta = interfaz.saveContador(93847597L);
                        respuesta.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(Response<String> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
                                //Some logging
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                                //Some logging
                            }
                        });
```

[Link](https://futurestud.io/blog/retrofit-2-upgrade-guide-from-1-9/?utm_source=Android%20Weekly&utm_campaign=553bcbfc02-Android_Weekly_174&utm_medium=email&utm_term=0_4eb677ad19-553bcbfc02-337921417) for reference

Comment: Glad I could help. Cheers!